# How can I unzip a zip file in windows using puppet script

Tags: windows, puppet

I am new to puppet
I want to unzip a zip file kept in puppet windows agent.

```
class ziptest {
exec {"test" :
command =>'unzip Test.zip',
cwd =>  'D:\',
path => 'D:\',
    }
}
```

While execution I am getting an error :

```
COULD NOT FIND COMMAND UNZIP
```

Answer (score 4):

Theres a [puppet module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/counsyl/windows) for windows configurations that includes an unzip type.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to unzip an archive with the module counsyl/windows on Win7. Instead, I have another working solution. Problem ist, windows does not have a built-in command line tool to unzip an archive.

Solution:
1. Copy 7za.exe on agent (Download [here: www.7-zip.org](http://www.7-zip.org))
2. Run exec to unzip file

How to copy 7za:

```
class sevenzip {

$location = '\\SERVER\path\7za920\7za.exe'
$local_file = 'C:\Windows\System32\7za.exe'

file { $local_file:
    ensure => file,
    source => $location,
    source_permissions => ignore
    }
}
```

How to run 7za:

```
class install_updates_win {

$location = '\\SERVER\path\PSWindowsUpdate.zip'
$local_file = 'C:\PSWindowsUpdate.zip'
$destination = 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\PSWindowsUpdate'

file { $local_file:
    ensure => file,
    source => $location,
    source_permissions => ignore,
}

exec { 'extract-pswindowsupdate':
    command   => "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:/Windows/System32/7za.exe e $local_file -o$destination -y",
    cwd       => 'C:/',
    logoutput => true, 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am new to puppet as well and had the same issue. :) It is possible to call powershell from puppet using the ps module: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/powershell

```
exec { "unzip" :
  command => "Expand-Archive -Path $source -DestinationPath $destination -Force", 
  provider  => powershell,
  logoutput => true,
}
```

or without the module just calling the ps.exe

```
exec { "unzip":
  command   => "C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -command Expand-Archive -Path $source -DestinationPath $destination -Force",
  logoutput => true,
}
```

I am using expand archive which requires PS 4 so I will have to do some version check as well to be on the safe side.

I think you can write a class which is using unzip on linux machines and PS on Windows machines.

```
define zip::expandarchive($source, $destination) {

  if $::kernel == 'windows' {
    exec { "unzip with ps ($source, $destination)":
        command   => "C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe -command Expand-Archive -Path $source -DestinationPath $destination -Force",
        logoutput => true,
    }
  }
  else {
    exec { "unzip ($source, $destination)":
      command   => "unzip -o -d $destination $source",
      logoutput => true,
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
zip::expandarchive { 'ziptest' :
  source => 'D:/Test.zip', 
  destination => 'D:',
}
```

Using cygwin seems to work as well but you need to select the zip and unzip tools when you install it. Also adding bin folder to the PATH is not working so you need the full path (let me know if you know how to fix this):

```
exec { 'unzip package':
  command   => "c:/cygwin64/bin/unzip.exe -o -d $destination $source",
  logoutput => true,
}
```